# Storing and retrieving OAuth token used by API package - .Rprofile vs. .Renviron, getOption vs. Sys.getenv

Tags: r, oauth-2.0, r-package, httr

I need to store a personal API OAuth token that is used by an R API package.  I'm developing and testing this package so am both the user with the personal API key and the developer in control of how the token is retrieved by the functions.

I've seen suggestions to:

1) Put the token in the .Rprofile file like `options(this_api_token = "fdmkdmfd393")` and access it via `getOption("this_api_token")`.

2) Put the token in the .Renviron file like `this_api_token = "fdmkdmfd393"` and access it via `Sys.getenv("this_api_token")`.

Both of those seem to retrieve the token.  Which combination of .Rprofile vs. .Renviron and `getOption` vs. `Sys.getenv` is preferable for this use case?

Comment: hey @sam-firke, how did you go about this?

Comment: I ended up going with option #1, using `getOption()`.  It worked fine.